# How do I write a regular expression for all lines followed by an empty line?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

Now, in the snippet below, you will notice that there is a list of file paths. Each section (preceded and followed by empty lines) represents a set of files that are duplicated. I would like to select all but one of these so that I can then inverse the selection and use the list for a batch delete operation. I have no idea on how to construct a regular expression for selecting the same though.

The regular expression would have to select all lines excluding one in each section. How would I write such an expression?

```
  "H:\S\recup_dir.17\f171236272.mp3"
  "H:\S\recup_dir.8\f37197984.mp3"

  "H:\S\recup_dir.16\f168470040.gz"
  "H:\S\recup_dir.17\f170038264.gz"

  "H:\S\recup_dir.18\f218780056.mp3"
  "H:\S\recup_dir.9\f46500864.mp3"

  "H:\S\recup_dir.1\f0712280.mp3"
  "H:\S\recup_dir.20\f330856896.mp3"

  "H:\S\recup_dir.20\f304869798.mp3"
  "H:\S\recup_dir.9\f50157574.mp3"

  "H:\S\recup_dir.19\f246711560.mp3"
  "H:\S\recup_dir.9\f49831408.mp3"

  "H:\S\recup_dir.14\f108337512.mp3"
  "H:\S\recup_dir.2\f8089064.mp3"

  "H:\S\recup_dir.16\f152853840.mp3"
  "H:\S\recup_dir.20\f315839720.mp3"
  "H:\S\recup_dir.8\f38617728.mp3"

  "H:\S\recup_dir.22\f414604664.mp3"
  "H:\S\recup_dir.8\f38191280.mp3"

  "H:\S\recup_dir.10\f52349328.mp3"
  "H:\S\recup_dir.22\f415832696.mp3"

  "H:\S\recup_dir.17\f171137807.mp3"
  "H:\S\recup_dir.20\f303943983.mp3"
  "H:\S\recup_dir.8\f37378127.mp3"

  "H:\S\recup_dir.15\f123439872.mp3"
  "H:\S\recup_dir.2\f7974272.mp3"

  "H:\S\recup_dir.2\f6994232.mp3"
  "H:\S\recup_dir.20\f281329576.mp3"
```

Comment: In which language/tool you want this regex?

Comment: I'll be using it for a selection in Sublime Text 2.

Comment: Is [this](http://regex101.com/r/nN2fT2) the selection you're trying to obtain?

Comment: @Jerry, that is close. And I realise that the title of this question is misleading because I have no idea on how else to frame it, but no. That only selects the last line in each section. I want all but the first.

Comment: as @anubhava suggested, in which language you want this regular expression? Also i dos not get your problem

Comment: Siddhart, hmm, maybe [this](http://regex101.com/r/tB4mM4) instead? I'm downloading ST2 to test if it works in the meantime.

Comment: @Jerry, that's fantastic! Could you please post it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<!\n\n)(?<!\A)^ *\S+
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/eQ8wU4).

The initial regex `(?<!\n\n|\A)^\S+` didn't work because of the variable width lookbehind I think, but I tested it on portable SublimeText 2.0.2. Might be something which works on v3.X.

<sup>(EDIT: Had to add extra spaces in regex)</sup>

Comment: Wait. This doesn't work now that I've tried. I suspect it's because if you notice, every line is padded with two spaces before the beginning of the string. Anyway to supersede that? Or I'll just delete the first two spaces from every line.

Comment: @Siddharth Ahh, I thought the spaces were from the formatting. You can use `(?<!\n\n)(?<!\A)^ *\S+` (I put a literal space there an not `\s` because `\s` matches newlines and would ruin things.)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a regex, you can just split on the two newlines.  For example, in JavaScript:

```
text.split('\n\n');
```

You could also use the regex `\n\n`, though -- or perhaps a bit safer would be `\n\s*\n`

Comment: Please read the description. I realise that I have framed the title incorrectly. I want to select all but the first line in each section.